# Hyper-V corruption on save/start

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, windows-10-pro, hyper-v-manager

I have set up a Windows 10 Pro VM on a Windows 10 Pro host. The guest is a Generation 2 VM and the settings veer off the defaults only to specify 16 GB max dynamic memory, 8 virtual CPUs, disable checkpoints, and enable a static MAC address. The host hardware has 32 GB RAM and a quad-core i7 (with hyper-threading).

The VM state is saved in the evening and restored the next day. However this seems to go wrong sometimes and corrupts the VM. Once the corruption happens, attempting to do anything else with the VM will make a vmms or vmwp process stuck doing something, loading the CPU around 100% of a single core without any sign of progress for as long as I've bothered waiting for it (20+ minutes, when it normally takes < 1 minute to restore the state). The vmms will stop communicating with Hyper-V Manager until the busy vmwp process is killed. The only fix I've found is to delete the VM and create a new one using the same disk file, which is fine but getting tedious as I have to do this every other week or so.

Is there any way to find out what's actually going wrong and avoid having to recreate the VM every time it happens?

Comment: Try with fewer CPUs  . Guest machines do not always benefit with so many CPUs, so try 2 CPU's and then see if the guest machine is free of save and start corruption.

Comment: Is this the hyper-v version of "have you tried turning it off and on again" or speaking from having had that problem yourself?

Comment: It has been a while, but latterly, I just use one CPU with 2 cores and get good results. I use VMware Workstation.